# Increase in the duration of chat suspension for [insert-here-the-user-who-shall-not-be-named]

Tags: discussion, chat, suspensions

Why was [insert-here-the-user-who-shall-not-be-named]'s chat suspension sentence increased from 24 hours to 29 days?

Comment: To reiterate our usual policy which dmckee mentioned in his answer, we do not discuss individual suspensions.

Answer (score 6):

The longer sentence was imposed after a day's consultation between the physics moderators; the delay occurred because we're always reluctant to impose suspensions on regular users and try not to act hastily in such cases.

As usually, we will not discuss the reasons in public, but [insert-here-the-user-who-shall-not-be-named] was sent a mod message and might divulge it's contents either after his return to chat or in some other place.

---

A couple of asides:

- I think it took effect some time after the one day suspension imposed by a passing moderator from another site had expired, rather than extending it.
- [*Toward a philosophy of Chat*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) is worth reading if you're thinking along the lines of "But *our* room culture...". There is only so much allowance for room culture.

Comment: I'd note that the system doesn't give us the ability to extend a suspension.